A movie scene with russian roulette in an army tent
Once in the late 1990's, I remember seeing a scene of a film on TV, where this guy walks into an army tent, and there's a bunch of strange people inside playing russian roulette. He get's invited to sit, and eventually gets someones blood splashed all over his face as the gun goes off. The next round of the game is with a live grenade, and at that point the guy hurries out of the tent. I'm pretty sure one of the players was dressed as a clown. I have no idea what the film was about, but seemed somewhat surreal.

If this was, indeed, a spoof (as alluded to in the answer below), take a look at this list and see if any ring a bell: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077416/movieconnections#spoofed_in

I don't think  the scene was a parody of the Deer Hunter. I went through the films on that list, just in case, but no match as far as I can tell. The film was broadcast on late night TV, and might have been an independent film by the feel of it. I think the "hero" got into tent by chance, to ask directions, etc.

Was it a comedy movie? It sounds like it could be a parody of The Deerhunter? A blind guess would be Hotshots Part Deux, but it's been years since I saw it.

Please don't spitball for an answer. Only answer if you think you have the answer. I suggest checking out the Tour to get a better idea of how to ask and answer questions here. We're not a typical discussion forum. Had you read the Tour you'd have the "Informed" badge. (We were all new here once, don't be discouraged.)

When you've got the Reputation Points (50) to comment, that's a fine place to speculate, BTW. That's part of what comments are for.

I was attempting to be helpful despite a restriction. Although I do.admit my answer was pretty vague. Cheers.
